# Controller unit testing symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am new in unit test case and I have one function

```
 /**
 * Creates a new Blog entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="blog_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("AppBundle:Blog:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Blog();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
} // End of method
```

which creates entries into the database. The problem is that I am not able to write a test case for validation of inputs submitted by the form, even I try to create an object of the controller and pass an entity into that. I don't know how to create a controller object in a test case and
how to validate the input form and view, any idea? 
[I'm looking for a solution like this](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/06/symfony2-testing-your-controllers/).

Comment: Maybe just unit test your validation only.

Comment: Did you read the comment at the beginning of that articles ? It doesn't make sense to unit test controllers. Try with functional test http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#forms

Comment: IMHO I do not believe that unit testing controllers is inappropriate. Functional tests are important but they will not be as good for testing a whole set of boundary conditions, a functional test is best for testing one 'happy' path and one 'unhappy' path, effectively testing that the 'glue' between layers is working. Now it is true that controllers should be as skinny as possible, so there should not be too much logic, but there is always some, as seen in the question. 
There are obviously argumets pro and contra for this, but a point-blank "don't do it" is not that helpful I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to instantiate the Controller as a partial mock. This will allow you to 'override' certain functions, in this case

- createCreateForm
- redirect
- getDoctrine
- generateUrl

You can the override these methods and get them to return mocked versions, or objects that your tests control. In the case of the redirect you can give the method expectations.

`$controller = $this->getMock(
    'MyController', 
    array(
          'createCreateForm', 
          'redirect',
          'getDoctrine',
          'generateUrl'
    )
);`

Comment: When i validate this controller method it shows me error
$controller
            ->expects($this->$this->any())
            ->method('redirect')
        ;
"Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times"